# Checkbox show div

Tags: jquery

Please can I have some assistance. I am more on the junior side of Jquery and this is driving me nuts.

I wish to open & close div class="div1" when I check & uncheck input class="mark" checkbox. The problem is that the number of div class="div1" and input class="mark" is dynamic depending on what I get from the database.

The jquery below is what I have tried and it is not working. I thought .next should work. How would I go about no matter how many input class=mark I generate, I can show, hide the div class="div1" that follows it?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".div1").hide();
 $(".mark").click(function() {
     $(this).next('.div1').toggle();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><?php echo "$code - $name"; ?></div>
<div class="panel-body">

<label>MARKETING?</label> 
<input class="mark" name="mark[]" type="checkbox" <?php if ($mark[$count] == 'Y') { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>

<div class="div1">

<label>Product + Price</label> 
<input name="mark1[]" type="checkbox" <?php if ($mark1[$count] == 'Y') { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/> 

<textarea class="form-control" name="markbox1[]" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($markbox1[$count]); ?></textarea>

<label>Plus 10</label> 
<input name="mark2[]" type="checkbox" <?php if ($mark2[$count] == 'Y') { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>

<textarea class="form-control" name="markbox2[]" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($markbox2[$count]); ?></textarea>

<label>Data</label> 
<input name="mark3[]" type="checkbox" <?php if ($mark3[$count] == 'Y') { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/> 

<textarea class="form-control" name="markbox3[]" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($markbox3[$count]); ?></textarea>

<label>Social Media</label> 
<input name="mark4[]" type="checkbox" <?php if ($mark4[$count] == 'Y') { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />

<textarea class="form-control" name="markbox4[]" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($markbox4[$count]); ?></textarea>

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you just generate a general/global class for all those specific divs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick?  I typically use show() instead of toggle() in this situation.  Also added an if statement in the event the checkbox is then unchecked.  Cheers

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".div1").hide();
    $(".mark").click(function() {
         if (".mark").is(":checked")) {
             $(this).next(".div1").show();
         } else {
             $(this).next(".div1").hide();
         };
    });
});
```